# Localization not supporting append function

Tags: java, localization

My program converts a String 7_example to Arabic.String is split into two `s[0]=7` and `s[1]=example`.
    String s[1] is converted to Arabic and stored as String Buffer,then my task is to append 7 at  the end position for that I use append function as below
    `convertedWord.append(s[0]);`

Why am i getting 7 at starting position? 
    Why append function is different in this case.I have tried with String append too but the result is same.

```
public String conversion(String data)
{
ResourceBundle obj1 = ResourceBundle.getBundle("ApplicationResources_ar_AR");
data= obj1.getString(Queries);  
return data;
}
```

*If it is an Alphabet or a word it is appending last,but for numbers its coming first

Comment: Too little code. Post the method/code you're using to do your transformation.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing it is because the Arabic language is from right to left, so the 7 is actually at the end of the string but it is displayed at the beginning position.

There are two things you may try to solve your problem:

**I - Append an additional dummy character, check if the 7 is displayed at the end then (you may try a space).**

Code:

```
StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer();
s.append(convertedWord);
s.append("7.");
String result = s.toString();
```

**II - Append the 7 at the starting position (use StringBuffer, check with and without spaces)**

Code:

```
StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer();
s.append(convertedWord);
s.insert(0," 7 ");
String result = s.toString();
```

Comment: Both suggestions didn't worked for me.If it is an Alphabet or a word it is appending last,but for numbers its coming first